# Different slide duration for each item on bootstrap 3.1 carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have different duration for each slide as my some slides have large content and some small please give me a solution with fiddle

I tried this but it only works on slide animation timing:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.1 carousel don't allow diferent duration for each slide, but it offers **one method** and **one event** that we can use in order to ahieve this.

We will use the `slid.bs.carousel` event to detect when the carousel has completed its slide transition and the `.carousel('pause')` option to stop the carousel from cycling through items.

We will use this attribute `data-interval="x"` on each carousel item with different time duration, so our html will look like this for example:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item" data-interval="3000">
        <img src="Url 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-interval="6000">
        <img src="Url 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-interval="9000">
        <img src="Url 3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, all we have to do is to:

1. detect when a new item is displayed using the `slid.bs.carousel`
   event
2. check his duration
3. pause the carousel using `.carousel('pause')`
4. set a timeout with the duration of the item and after the duration
   completed we should unpause the carousel

The javascript code will look like this:

```
var t;

var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start-1000);

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   
     clearTimeout(t);  
     var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');

     $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
     t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration-1000);
})

$('.carousel-control.right').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);   
});

$('.carousel-control.left').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);   
});
```

As you can see, we are forced at the begining to add a starting interval and i've set it to 1000ms but i remove it each time i pause the carousel `duration-1000`. I've used the lines below to resolve the first item problem because that item was not caught by the `slid event`.

```
var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start-1000);
```

I also noticed that if the user presses the arrows, the timeout is going crazy, that's why i clear the timeout each time the user press on the left and right arrow.

Here is my live example http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/52KBT/, hope this response was helpful for you.

Comment: Hi I'd like some help please if possible.. I'm having a problem with the duration of the sliders, it seems that the script doesn't work with the `data-duration`.. Here's the link to my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198883/bootstrap-set-different-interval-on-each-carousel-item

Comment: You have here everything you need in order to make it work, you got here even a working example. Now it's up to you to adapt it to your code. As you see in this jsfiddle example it works very fine, you just need to take some time and understand what you need to do.

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nfm0zv6h/ what's wrong?? I have run through my code many times, but I can't figure out why the carousel starts, for the first time only, the 1st slide pauses for 4 sec, when it supposed to be 8 .. when it starts from the beggining again it pauses for 8sec as expected

Comment: You need to load the bootstrap.js library using external file. Currently is missing.

Comment: Sorry forgot it.. You can check now

Comment: You did not add it. It is missing. Anyways, it seems that you have very big issues understanding html/css/javascript, so you should not use twitter bootstrap until you can handle basic things. You have everything that you need in this page, even a simple working example, if you can't replicate this it means you need to take if from the start, with the basic html, css and javascript.

Comment: Duration interval is  not working when html5 videos are included in carousel..Can anyone help me to set the duration of videos in this carousel?

Comment: thank you @paulalexandru, but your solution disable on hover pause feature, is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: @MohseTaheri Hi, please add a jsfiddle example with your code I will look it up and see if I can fix it. Cheers

Comment: @paulalexandru sorry i don't see your comment until now, you can check it on your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/52KBT/  I'm using firefox quantom on ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **thank you @paulalexandru**. Your code at first didn't work for me, however making some changes, I was able to achieve the expected result. The main issue was related to the element not finding the **duration-interval**, so I used javascript instead of jquery (I'm still a beginner on it). So the following code worked for me (I'm keeping the old code as comment)

```
var t;
//var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
var start = document.getElementsByClassName("item active")[0].getAttribute("data-interval");


t = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('next')
}, start);

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    clearTimeout(t);
    //var duration = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
    var duration = document.getElementsByClassName("item active")[0].getAttribute("data-interval");

    $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
    t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel('next');", duration);
    console.log(duration);
})

$('.carousel-control.right').on('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
});

$('.carousel-control.left').on('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" data-interval="3000">
        <img class="first-slide carousel-image-background">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2 class="carousel-h2">My title</h2>
                    <p class="carousel-p">My description text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the pause method did seem to work for me. So, I used the following code and it worked for me. This works even if you have multiple carousels on the same page. This approach however requires the data-interval attribute mandatory against each carousel item.

```
var t;
var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');

t = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('next')
}, start);

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    clearTimeout(t);
    var duration = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');

    //$('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
    t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel('next');", duration);
})

$('.carousel-control.right').on('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
});

$('.carousel-control.left').on('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
});
```

Comment: This is cleaner IMO. The pause on @paulalexandru 's otherwise excellent post added unnecessary complexity, especially when using modified crossfade (transition) times. Make sure you leave off the data-ride="carousel" of the carousel itself. Using the code above, javascript handles all the slide change work.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.carousel .item').hasClass('active', function() {
    var SlideInterval = $(this).attr('data-interval');
    $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: SlideInterval });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This doesn't solve the feature of having a different interval per item, but simply sets the same interval for all items.

Answer (score -2):

**In case if you are looking for Angular solution, please below link**

[Add interval for each mdb-carousel item in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927344/add-interval-for-each-mdb-carousel-item-in-angular/67947718#67947718)

Here is the extract from the link:
In HTML, we need to pass the carousel component back to the Typescript using activeSlideChange method available for the slide event. Also need to add ids for each carousel item for reference

-- HTML

```
<div>
  <mdb-carousel  #carousal  [interval]="1000" [isControls]="false" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" [animation]="'fade'"
  (activeSlideChange)="activeSlideChange(carousal)" >
    <mdb-carousel-item id='home'>
      <!-- THIS NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED FOR 5 SECS -->
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
    </mdb-carousel-item>

    <mdb-carousel-item id='time'>
      <!-- THIS NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED FOR 15 SECS -->
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </mdb-carousel-item>
  </mdb-carousel>
</div>
```

In typescript, we can define the activeSlideChange method like this

```
 activeSlideChange(cc: CarouselComponent){
   let slideItem = cc.slides[cc.activeSlide];
   let id = slideItem.el.nativeElement.id;
   console.log(id);
    if ( id === 'home') {
        cc.interval = 1000 * 5 ; // 5 secs
    } else if ( id === 'time') { 
      cc.interval = 1000 * 15; // 15 secs
    }else  {
      cc.interval = 5000;
    }
  }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29181359)

Comment: I thought of avoiding duplicating the solution. However it make sense if the link will be deleted. Thanks for your review