# Change Bootstrap Interval at runtime

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

you can use the following code to initialize the bootstrap carousel with a specific interval:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000 
});
```

But how do you change that interval if you want, for example, each slide to have a specific interval?

I've added data-interval attributes to each slide's div element like so:

```
<div class="item active" data-interval="7000">
<div class="item active" data-interval="5000">
<div class="item active" data-interval="4000">
```

Using Bootstrap's 'slide' event I'd like to reset the interval based on the data- attribute value. The value I can get so there's no problem there, but do I just use 'options' to set the interval and it will work?

```
$('.carousel').options.inteval = 10000;
```

**Edit: Suggested solution not optimal**
It has been suggested that the following link may be an answer to my question: [Different slide duration for each item on bootstrap 3.1 carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300199/different-slide-duration-for-each-item-on-bootstrap-3-1-carousel)

The user is suggesting the use of timeouts which for me seems to cause issues in IE9. I suspect that there are issues with how these timeouts are potentially interfering with Bootstraps carousel intervals. 
**End Edit**

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300199/different-slide-duration-for-each-item-on-bootstrap-3-1-carousel

Comment: have you tried your idea? did it work?

Comment: @DLeh Yeah I get the following: TypeError: $(...).options is undefined

Comment: @brothers28 I think that post is what we've actually got at the moment but it causes some serious problems in IE9 which is what I'm trying to fix right now. The problem with that post is that it's making use of setTimeout, wouldn't that interfere with the carousel's own timers/intervals?

Comment: @Jacques Could you just pause the carousel and then use the timeout for the current slide and call next for the next slide when that timeout fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually wasn't far off.

```
$(function ()
{

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000 //set the initial interval
    });

    //handle Bootstrap carousel slide event
    $('.carousel').on("slide.bs.carousel", function (e)
    {
        //get the next interval from the data- HTML attribute
        var interval = parseInt($(e.relatedTarget).data("interval"));

        //set the interval by first getting a reference to the widget
        $('.carousel').data("bs.carousel").options.interval =  interval;
    });
});
```