# bootstrap carousel change interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[Different slide duration for each item on bootstrap 3.1 carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300199/different-slide-duration-for-each-item-on-bootstrap-3-1-carousel) shows a way to change the interval for each individual slide. My ignorance is profound; I'm not adept with either Bootstrap or Javascript, and I don't dare try to modify `carousel.js`.  How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: All the html, css and  and code is in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/52KBT/). Did you open it?

Comment: Yes.  I've never used Javascript from an external linked file before.  My pages are linked to http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css, https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js, and http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js.   I know what to do to customize the CSS; I look at the external CSS file, identify the class or id I want to modify, and add my modifications under the same class or id, in my own CSS file (linked in after the boostrap.min.css file). I do not know how to do the same thing with Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some simple instructions to utilize the code from the jsfiddle.
The jsfiddle referenced in the link you provided has all the code you need to implement it.

1. Make a blank plain text file and call it *custom.js* ( or anything.js you want).
2. Place this code from the jsfiddle in that file and save it:

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var t;

  var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
 t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start-1000);

 $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {  
  clearTimeout(t);  
  var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');

  $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
  t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration-1000);
  });

 $('.carousel-control.right').on('click', function(){
 clearTimeout(t);   
 });

 $('.carousel-control.left').on('click', function(){
 clearTimeout(t);   
 });
 });
```

3. you will need to put the custom.js file somewhere on your site and load it into your page after jQuery and bootstrap.js. You will need to set the path to the file.

Script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="your path to/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works, but the carousel no longer will pause on mouseover.

Comment: If you read the documentation for bootstrap  carousel, you can add `data-pause="hover"` to your `.carousel` div. With that said, this code from the other stack overflow question may interfere with that. The price for having different slide intervals for each slide.

Comment: Pause:'hover' is the default value, and it was working normally before. I agree, the modification interferes with pause-on-hover.  I lack the JS knowledge to tinker with it successfully.

Comment: Your question was about how to implement the code from the linked jsfiddle, BTW, which was answered,  yet not accepted. The fact that hover is not working is a separate question.