# Bootstrap - set different interval on each carousel item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hi I'm having a carousel on Bootstrap and what I'd like to do is to set each item to a different interval, so basically the first item could have a duration of 10 sec, the 2nd 5 sec the 3rd 3sec etc etc ..

Therefore I decided to use a data attribute like this

```
  <!-- Carousel -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"  class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active" data-interval="8000">
                    <img src="carousel/icon_1.jpg" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h2 class="carousel-title">Welcome to My Site</h2>
                         <p class="carousel-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        <p class="carousel-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                   </div>
            </div><!-- /.item -->


            <div class="item" data-interval="4000">
                <img src="carousel/icon_2.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
            </div><!-- /.item -->


            <div class="item" data-interval="4000">
                <img src="carousel/icon_3.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
            </div><!-- /.item -->


        </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->

</div> <!-- Carousel -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
            // more scripts here ...

// the main part
            var t;
            var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
            t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start-1000);

            $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   
                 clearTimeout(t);  
                 var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');

                 $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
                 t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration-1000);
            });
        });
</script>
```

in case I might need to change a time interval in future. The problem is that all slides apply the same interval (about 2 or 1 sec). How can I fix this?

Comment: In case if you are looking for Angular solution, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927344/add-interval-for-each-mdb-carousel-item-in-angular/67947718#67947718)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you have followed is correct but you need to capture `sliding event` of `twitter-bootstrap carousel` to make it work as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/52KBT/74/)**

```
var t;
var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout(function(){
         $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000})
    }, start-1000);

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   
     clearTimeout(t);  
     var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');

     $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
     t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration-1000);
})

$('.carousel-control.right').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);   
});

$('.carousel-control.left').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);   
});
```

For more detailed version visit **[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303140/2065039)**

Comment: It doesn't seems to work for me.. I have set the 1st slide to 5000, and the rest to 2000 msec but ALL  slideshave same duration (2000 msec)

Comment: @lykos Its working fine!! Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/52KBT/75/) updated with the structure given by you!!

Comment: I 've update my code so you can also do a check..

Comment: In case if you are looking for Angular solution, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927344/add-interval-for-each-mdb-carousel-item-in-angular/67947718#67947718)