# Owl Carousel Autoplaytimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel-2

Is it possible to have different autoplayTimeout for different items inside a carousel block.
Item1(image) - timeout - 5000,
Item2(image) - timeout - 8000,
Item3(image) - timeout - 10000

something like this.

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300199/different-slide-duration-for-each-item-on-bootstrap-3-1-carousel  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items